# Sphinx 1.4+ and block literals in Returns with sphinx-napoleon don't work anymore

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-napoleon

I am writing documentation for a python project that follows this guide:

http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html

To be exact this part of the guide:

The `Returns` section supports any reStructuredText formatting, including literal blocks::

My code looks as follows:

```
Returns:
    None:

    ::

        {
            "status": "update",
            "success": True,
        }
```

For sphinx 1.3.5-1.3.6 it works as expected.

For sphinx 1.4.0-1.4.1 it throws error like that:

```
api/v0_0/views.py:docstring of api.v0_0.views.add_gallery:19: ERROR: Unexpected indentation.
api/v0_0/views.py:docstring of api.v0_0.views.add_gallery:21: WARNING: Block quote ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.
```

Comment: Then shouldn't you report this as a bug?

Comment: I am not sure if it's error or change of some sort. :-D

Comment: But that idea crossed my mind, that maybe it's a bug.

Comment: If it's a change that broke your code, it's either a regression or should be listed in the release notes as a breaking change - either way, this isn't something SO can really help with.

Comment: I put a bug report on python-sphinx, when and if I have update, will post it in here. If it's bug I will note it, if it's my lack of knowledge, I will explain what to do.

Comment: I have opened a ticket on Sphinx project itself. As soon as I have some feedback I will let you know.

Comment: It seems like indentation is messed up. Maybe you can check with `cat -t -e sourceFile` to play around with tabs.

Comment: Indentation is ok, changing version of sphinx alone is enough to fix it. Plus my vim corrects such basic things for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was bug. I have created a ticket with working example how to reproduce it. Guys working on Sphinx have fixed it week (or so) later. Bumping version will solve it.